# QTreeView QFileSystemModel - limit expandable to only root

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside, qtreeview, qfilesystemmodel

I'm using QTreeView and QFileSystemModel. I want *only* the root to be expandable, showing 1 level of subdirectory and that's it, the subdirectories should only be selectable but not expandable. Any guidance how I can archive this please?

Thank you.

Comment: You can create a filter proxy model that does it. No changes are necessary to the view.

Answer (score 2):

As previously suggested, you can create a proxy model to modify the model's behavior:

```
class Proxy : public QSortFilterProxyModel {
public:
  static int indexLevel(QModelIndex index) {
    int level = 0;
    while(index.parent().isValid()) {
      level++;
      index = index.parent();
    }
    return level;
  }

  int rowCount(const QModelIndex& parent) const {
    if (indexLevel(parent) > 0) {
      return 0;
    }
    return QSortFilterProxyModel::rowCount(parent);
  }

  bool hasChildren(const QModelIndex& parent) const {
    if (indexLevel(parent) > 0) {
      return false;
    }
    return QSortFilterProxyModel::hasChildren(parent);
  }
};

//...
QFileSystemModel model;
model.setRootPath(QString());
Proxy proxy;
proxy.setSourceModel(&model);
QTreeView view;
view.setModel(&proxy);
view.show();
```